# Xcode 8.2.1 / Swift 3 - Load TableView from Plist Array of Dictionaries

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a plist that I copied into my project to use it in a TableView.  The plist loads and I verified by printing the contents and number of rows to the console.  When I build the project, I get a blank TableView with no data though.  I've searched and tried for days, but still can't get it to display.  Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "directory", ofType: "plist")
    let employees = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!) as! [[String: String]]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (employees.count)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Name"]) //as! String)
        cell.positionLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Position"]) //as! String)

        return cell
    }

    for item in employees {

        print(item["Name"] as Any)
        print(item.count)
        print(employees.count)
    }
```

And here is some of the plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
      <key>Department</key>
      <string>Operations</string>
      <key>Position</key>
      <string>Operator </string>
      <key>Name</key>
      <string>John Smith</string>
      <key>Email</key>
      <string>john.smith@nospam.net</string>
      <key>Cell Phone</key>
      <string>123-456-7890</string>
      <key>Office Phone</key>
      <string></string>
</dict>
<dict>
      <key>Department</key>
      <string>Sales</string>
      <key>Position</key>
      <string>Salesperson</string>
      <key>Name</key>
      <string>Susan Brown</string>
      <key>Email</key>
      <string>susan.brown@nospam.net</string>
      <key>Cell Phone</key>
      <string>234-567-8901</string>
      <key>Office Phone</key>
      <string>345-678-9012</string>
</dict>
```

And here is the other swift file the code references:

```
import UIKit
class TableViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var positionLabel: UILabel!
```

Thanks in advance!  Seriously pulling hair out....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to set your tableView delegate and datasource. Add the following lines to your `viewDidLoad`.

```
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
```

You also want to move your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` functions out of `viewDidLoad` and add the word `override` in front of them.

Full code:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var filePath: String?
    var employees: [[String: String]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "directory", ofType: "plist")
        employees = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath!) as! [[String: String]]

        for item in employees {

            print(item["Name"] as Any)
            print(item.count)
            print(employees.count)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (employees.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Name"]) //as! String)
        cell.positionLabel.text = (employees[indexPath.row]["Position"]) //as! String)

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Justin.  When I move the two functions and add override, it then can't find the employees variable and gives "Use of unresolved identifier 'employees'".  I added "var employees = [[String:String]]()" under class, it builds, but I get a blank TableView.  If I leave the two functions in viewDidLoad, it builds, but I still get the blank TableView.  The TableView is loaded via segue from a button on the main ViewController.

Comment: Simply move the variable declarations to a class scope outside of `viewDidLoad`. I've updated my example code above.

Comment: Thanks again Justin.  I copied and pasted, but now it's showing error:  Cannot use instance member 'filePath' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.  I looked it up and haven't figured out resolution yet.

Comment: Suhweet!  I can't tell you how much I appreciate your help!