# Swift 3: Populating plist data to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

early this month i started learning swift as i found it fun and easier than obj-c

i came up with an idea trying to show english words and meaning on my language,

for that case i have a plist ready on my hand and a UITableViewController
with 2 Labels

here is my plist 
[image: Click to view]

so on my UITableViewController, i tried to get hands on the plist file with this code

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("TableData", ofType: "plist")
 let array = Array(contentsOfFile: path!)
```

and i got stuck on the rest 
thanks

Comment: Looks like you didn't even search on SO for similar questions.. You can find a bunch of questions like this, eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124949/xcode-8-2-1-swift-3-load-tableview-from-plist-array-of-dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just staring to learn Swift **please start with Swift 3**. Your Swift 2 code is outdated.

The recommended way to load a property list file is `PropertyListSerialization`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TableData", withExtension: "plist")!
do {
   let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
   let dataArray = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[String:String]]
   print(dataArray)
} catch {
    print("This error must not happen", error)
}
```

Comment: thanks @vadian, this is not the first time you helping me truly! thanks again